# Why data will post on the same "window"

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to want to post data on many "windows", not just one.

To help explain what I am doing, here are some examples.

[**Screenshot 1**](http://screenshooter.net/101982629/LeviPlayGames_113)

Next, I want to post news on many windows like this:
[**Screenshot 2**](http://screenshooter.net/101982629/LeviPlayGames_115)

---

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="news">
        <div id="newsWindow">
            <div id="newsTitle">
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    $uchwyt=mysql_connect('=====','=====','=====')
                        or die('Nieudane polaczenie z baza danych...');
                            mysql_select_db('a6039035_news')
                        or die('Nie udalo sie wybrac bazy danych...');
                    $link=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 4");
                    while($wiersz=mysql_fetch_array($link))
                    {
                        echo $wiersz['tytul'];
                        echo "<br>\n";
                    }
                    mysql_close($uchwyt);
                ?>              
            </div>  
            <div id="newsInfo">
                <div class="time">
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    $uchwyt=mysql_connect('=====','=====','=====')
                        or die('Nieudane polaczenie z baza danych...');
                            mysql_select_db('a6039035_news')
                        or die('Nie udalo sie wybrac bazy danych...');
                    $link=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 4");
                    while($wiersz=mysql_fetch_array($link))
                    {
                        echo $wiersz['godzina'];
                    }
                    mysql_close($uchwyt);
                ?>  
                </div>
                <div class="date">
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    $uchwyt=mysql_connect('=====','=====','=====')
                        or die('Nieudane polaczenie z baza danych...');
                            mysql_select_db('a6039035_news')
                        or die('Nie udalo sie wybrac bazy danych...');
                    $link=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 4");
                    while($wiersz=mysql_fetch_array($link))
                    {
                        echo $wiersz['data'];
                    }
                    mysql_close($uchwyt);
                ?>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="newsContent">
                <p>
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    $uchwyt=mysql_connect('=====','=====','====')
                        or die('Nieudane polaczenie z baza danych...');
                            mysql_select_db('a6039035_news')
                        or die('Nie udalo sie wybrac bazy danych...');
                    $link=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 4");
                    while($wiersz=mysql_fetch_array($link))
                    {
                        echo $wiersz['tresc'];
                    }
                    mysql_close($uchwyt);
                ?>  
                </p>

                <div id="newsMore">
                    <a href="#">Czytaj więcej...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Simply create a new window and fill it with news

Comment: Im trying, but not working as I want.
Can you send me example of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a query and loop in each news `<div>`. You need to do the query before, and then loop over each news `<div>` and returned data

```
<?php
  $uchwyt=mysql_connect('=====','=====','=====')
    or die('Nieudane polaczenie z baza danych...');
  mysql_select_db('a6039035_news')
    or die('Nie udalo sie wybrac bazy danych...');
  $link=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 4");
?>
    <div id="news">
    <?php
      while($wiersz=mysql_fetch_array($link))
       { 
    ?>
    <div class="newsWindow">
        <div class="newsTitle">
            <?php
                    echo $wiersz['tytul'];
                    echo "<br>\n";
            ?>              
        </div>  
        <div class="newsInfo">
            <div class="time">
            <?php
                    echo $wiersz['godzina'];
            ?>  
            </div>
            <div class="date">
            <?php
                    echo $wiersz['data'];
            ?>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="newsContent">
            <p>
            <?php
                    echo $wiersz['tresc'];
            ?>  
            </p>
            <div id="newsMore">
                <a href="#">Czytaj więcej...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
       }
    ?>
```